# R - Leaflet Code "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'address.lon' not found"

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, dplyr

I'm trying to re-appropriate a Leaflet code I used six months ago, with which I had no problem at the time. I haven't used Leaflet since then and am now no longer able to generate maps like I was before.

Simply put, after switching out the variables in the same way I have for many other maps 6 months ago, I am receiving the following error message and am not sure how to fix it: *Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : object 'address.lon' not found*

I loaded the appropriate packages and data formats. Basic troubleshooting has been addressed. How do I fix this?

The contextual code is the following:

```
Example Data
org dept address latitude longitude
ABC, Inc., SPSG, 111111 North Whatever Houston, TX 77058, 29.5431888, -95.1023828
DEF, Inc., Security Systems, 111 North Sepulveda boulevard 2000 El Segundo, CA 90245, 42.6379953, -71.2459721


df %>%  
mutate(popup_info=paste(sep = "<br/>", paste0("<b>","<i>", org,"<i>", "</b>"), dept)) %>% 
filter(!is.na(longitude) & !grepl("CLOSED", org)) %>% 
filter(!is.na(latitude) & !grepl("CLOSED", org)) -> df1

## Plot the Maps
# Client Map
orgpal <- colorFactor(plasma(7), df1$org) 
leaflet(df1) %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
addCircleMarkers(lng = ~longitude, 
               lat = ~latitude, 
               radius = 2.5, 
               fillColor = ~orgpal(orgpal),
               stroke=FALSE,
               fillOpacity = 1,
               popup = ~popup_info) %>%
addLegend("bottomright", pal = orgpal, values = ~org, labels = "Organization", title = "Client Locations") %>%
addMiniMap(tiles = providers$CartoDB.PositronNoLabels, width = 120, height=80)
```

Am I misunderstanding the function of address.lon? I apologize if my lack of understanding of coding prevents me from seeing an easy fix, I just haven't interacted with this code in a while. I appreciate any help I can receive.

Comment: Are you sure `address.lon` is a column in your dataset? It doesn't appear to be from your comment. Not sure what you were trying to accomplish in that `mutate()`. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input so we can run and test the code ourselves.

Comment: Double-check that `address.lon` is a column in your `df` - just check that that's the correct name in the csv you are reading in. Otherwise, change that to whatever the correct name should be.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' feedback. That was helpful. I gave a response to @sconfluentus, if you're interested in seeing where this has gone.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is failing because your `address.lon` in the `ifelse` statement refers to nothing in your obvious local environment based on the code included.

It is not in `"sp"` package, or `"rgdal"` or `"leaflet"` , you have not defined it yourself as a function and I cannot see where you have loaded access to it prior to calling it.

It is also, NOT another column in your data frame. So, R has nowhere to pull that from when it reaches it in your code.

It is my guess that your prior leaflet project had more preceding code than this and `address.lon` was defined in it.

If you post all of that code in an edit, or link to it in a file somewhere out in the wilds of the web, one of us could probably help you figure out both what `address.lon` does, and how to get it working in this mapping script.

Comment: I removed address.lon. I recognized the error when you mentioned it. I have made edits above due to your feedback, including adding the data.frame format. 
I now have a different error with my above code which is similar. I receive an error message saying:
Error in as.character(x) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' 
In addition: Warning messages: 
1: In validateCoords(lng, lat, funcName): Data contains 1 rows with either missing or invalid lat/lon values and will be ignored 
2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

Comment: run the function `str(df)` on your data frame and it will likely give me the clues I need to fix that problem. My guess is that your lat lon variables are coming in as character instead of numerical data.

Comment: Hey @sconfluentus, I ran str but to no effect. The error message is still: Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'
2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'closure'

I also ran sapply(df$latitude, class) verifying that it is indeed numeric. So, no change. Also, did you see the edits I made from your suggestions? I provide a small list of df variables. Thoughts?